# My friend is obsessed with smoking pot

Tags: the-last-guardian

While trying to solve the blue-pot-and-chain puzzle in The Last Guardian, I encountered a situation where I can't tell if it's just broken and/or unproceedable, or if there's just more puzzle that I haven't figured out yet.

I'll leave the details in spoiler blocks because puzzle, but in short and as unspoilery as possible, I know exactly where I need to go next, and exactly how to get there, but Trico is just…staring…at the smoking blue pot and won't come when I call him. Nothing I do seems to affect the situation at all.

Detailed description:

> I have, to the best of my knowledge, solved the puzzle perfectly: I hung the blue pot on the chain, Trico tugged at it enough to open the gate, and I up-ended the cog and slid it under the gate to keep it open. Then I tugged out the glow-barrel and tossed it under the ledge I need to climb up to.
>
>  At this point, everything is working exactly as the walkthroughs suggest it should: Trico squeezes through the gate, eats the barrel, at which point I can (theoretically) climb up on him and proceed to the next area.
>
>  However, I was unable to climb up him in time (controls amirite) and he eventually just started doing his own thing and wandering around, which included wandering back into the blue pot room.
>
>  Now he's just…staring…at the pot with his glazed yellow eyes. He won't come when I call him, he won't respond to my commands (not like he ever does that anyway&hellip) and even just waiting for him to get bored and wander around accomplishes nothing. He just loves that pot.
>
>  I've tried to remove the pot so I can hide it or something, but hitting circle just starts climbing the chain instead. Shoving it (or Trico) accomplishes nothing. He won't respond to R1 if I call him into the next room, or any of the R1 commands.
>
>  All the walkthroughs I've checked (after about an hour of fruitless Trico-herding; I do like solving puzzles myself, but after a point "How do I solve this puzzle?" just gives way to "Is this even a puzzle at all or just broken?") basically end after tossing the barrel; climb Trico, proceed to next area (and, for reference, I eventually just reloaded from last checkpoint and was able to proceed right away at that point).

Basically, I just want to know if there's an additional piece of the puzzle that I'm missing here, or if it's something I theoretically just need to wait out. Or is it actually a broken situation where loading from the previous checkpoint is really the only way to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

I got stuck here too! I did everything right, up til the point where we were set to leave to the next area. But then I thought, maybe there really was a way to feed that smoke pot to Trico and I was cruel for not trying harder to do so... So I went back. Bad idea; after following me back into that room, Trico became glued there to that pot.

I tried a lot of things but in the end I think there was no solution, it must have been broken. Poor kid didn't deserve it, but I even tried jumping to death right in front of Trico to reset the situation, but the fall wasn't enough to kill him. To add salt to the wound, Trico still paid him no mind even when the boy called out to him weakly in pain. That blue smoke pot is the cruelest unintentional enemy in the game.

...Resetting from last checkpoint as you did made a lot more sense and did the trick. Ha!